# Notification on emulator is not working

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to add a simple notification on Android emulator. I have taken the code from [Notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification) on the android developer website. I have used the code to run on emulator but there is a no notification. Am I missing any permission or some kind of setting, can anyone please help me.

```
public class SampleNotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_notification);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sendNotification();
}

private void sendNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder
            = new NotificationCompat.Builder(SampleNotificationActivity.this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Notification cool")
            .setContentText("My Very first Notification");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);


    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(SampleNotificationActivity.this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(100, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Comment: can you add full code to see the full class?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira, I have added the Activity class

Comment: what happens if you add the sendnotification to oncreate.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira, moving the sendNotification to onCreate did not create any effect. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if is this the problem, but probably you forgot to create the pending intent **correctly**.

You have **this**:

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Try **change** to:

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(this,0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Comment: Aah... the code was working on Device and emulator with API 24. Problem is with the emulator that I have API 26. Thanks for the help @Bruno